# How do I test for the existence of an HTML element inside an iframe using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

It's possible to test for the existence of an HTML element using jQuery.  For one example:

- [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

It is possible to do the same for an element that is inside an iframe?  My best attempt:

```
if($("#frameId").contents().find('elementName').length > 0)
{
  // do something with the element
}
```

EDIT: To avoid chasing the cross-domain rabbit, assume that yes, the files are (will be) in the same domain.

Comment: Good question.  Both are from the local file system at the moment (while in dev).  Eventually the HTML page will be served from a domain and the contents of the iframe will be drag-and-dropped from the local file system.

Comment: For your dev environment you must check the same-origin policy for files specific for your browser. This is the one for mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3A_URIs for your domain your pages must be from the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted the right answer, but then deleted it.  Don't know why.  This is what worked:

```
if($("#frameId").contents().find('elementName').length)
{
  // do something with the element
}
```

Thanks, Mystery Man!

Answer (score 1):

This question has many duplicates on stackoverflow (and possibly all across the internet too). Basically, your `iframe` *must* be on the same domain of the the app..

check this post for more details:
[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only if the i-frame is on the same domain as the main page otherwise this won't work.
If they are on the same domain this will work correctly.